# Sharing views and content across Nancy projects

Tags: nancy

Is there a super duper happy path for sharing views and site content across Nancy projects?

For example, I'd like to run the same site via self hosted / IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to put all of the actual application code into a class library - that is your modules, views, js, css, bootstrapper and whatever supporting code you have. You then setup a [view location convention](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/View-location-conventions) in your `Bootstrapper` such the view can be found in both a web server and self hosted context. This could be the `ResourceViewLocationProvider`:

```
  public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
  {
      protected override NancyInternalConfiguration InternalConfiguration
      {
          get
          {
              return NancyInternalConfiguration.WithOverrides(
                 x => x.ViewLocationProvider = typeof (ResourceViewLocationProvider));
          }
       }
   }
```

Alongside that you can have a web projects, with e.g. `nancy.hosting.owin` setup up and a project reference to the class library with the application code. Similarly you can have a console application with just `nancy.hosting.self` setup and a reference to the class library.

I describe this setup in more detail on my [blog](http://www.horsdal-consult.dk/2011/11/frictionless-net-web-app-development.html) and in my [Nancy book](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/instant-nancy-web-development-instant).